# padding='same' conversion to PyTorch padding=#

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, padding

I'm trying to convert the following Keras model code to pytorch, but am having problems dealing with padding='same'.

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=img_size))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
```

Which produces the following summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 30, 30, 64)        1792      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 30, 30, 64)        120       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 30, 30, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 30, 30, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 30, 30, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 30, 30, 64)        120       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 30, 30, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 15, 15, 64)        0         
=================================================================
Total params: 38,960
Trainable params: 38,840
Non-trainable params: 120
```

Right now, I would write:

```
self.features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3,
                      bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(0.3),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, padding = ?
                      bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding = ?),
        )
```

Where padding should have numerical value. I was wondering if there is an easier way to calculate this since we're using padding='same'.

Also, the next line of the Keras model looks like:

```
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same'))
```

So I really need to brush up on how to calculate padding, especially after stride too. **From a rough eye only, is the padding 2?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

W:input volume size

F:kernel size

S:stride

P:amount of padding

size of output volume = (W-F+2P)/S+1

e.g.

input:7x7, kernel:3x3, stride:1, pad:0

output size = (7-3+2*0)/1+1 = 5 =>5x5

Answer (score 3):

```
self.features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3,
                      bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(0.3),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, padding = 1
                      bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding = 32),
        )
```

[image]

Comment: in summary, for maxpooling2d, if stride=kernel, P=W/2

Answer (score 3):

In PyTorch you can directly use integer in padding.

In convolution padding = 1 for 3x3 kernel and stride=1 is ~ "same" in keras.

And In MaxPool you should set padding=0 (default), for 2x2 kernel, stride=2 is ~ "same" in keras.

You can use Formula:

Out = (W+2P-K)/S + 1

**Let see some mathematical calculation:**

**For Convolution:**

Case 1:

input is 30x30, kernel_size(K) is 3x3, stride=1, padding=1:

Out = (30+2*1-3)/1 + 1 = floor(29/1) + 1 = 30 i.e 30x30 (~ padding="same")

Case 2:

input is 30x30, kernel_size(K) is 3x3, stride=1, padding=0:

Out = (30+2*0-3)/1 + 1 = floor(27/1) + 1 = 28 i.e 28x28 (~ padding="valid")

**For MaxPooling:**

Case 1:

input is 30x30, kernel_size(K) is 2x2, stride=2, padding=0:

Out = (30+2*0-2)/2 + 1 = floor(28/2) + 1 = 15 i.e 15x15 (~ padding="same")

Case 2:

input is 30x30, kernel_size(K) is 2x2, stride=2, padding=1:

Out = (30+2*1-2)/2 + 1 = floor(30/2) + 1 = 16 i.e 16x16 (~ padding="valid")

**Here is a program implemented in PyTorch same as above keras code:**

```py
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=1, bias=False),
    nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
    nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
    nn.Dropout(0.3),

    nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=1, bias=False),
    nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
    nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=2, padding=0)
)

X = torch.rand((1, 3, 30, 30))

print(model)
for layer in model:
    X = layer(X)
    print(X.shape)
```

Output:

```sh
Sequential(
  (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (2): ReLU()
  (3): Dropout(p=0.3, inplace=False)
  (4): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (5): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (6): ReLU()
  (7): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
)
torch.Size([1, 64, 30, 30])
torch.Size([1, 64, 30, 30])
torch.Size([1, 64, 30, 30])
torch.Size([1, 64, 30, 30])
torch.Size([1, 64, 30, 30])
torch.Size([1, 64, 30, 30])
torch.Size([1, 64, 30, 30])
torch.Size([1, 64, 15, 15])
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below `conv2d` when you want to use `padding = 'same'` as in  `keras` with `stride = 2`  or more

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Conv2dSame(torch.nn.Conv2d):

    def calc_same_pad(self, i: int, k: int, s: int, d: int) -> int:
        return max((math.ceil(i / s) - 1) * s + (k - 1) * d + 1 - i, 0)

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        ih, iw = x.size()[-2:]

        pad_h = self.calc_same_pad(i=ih, k=self.kernel_size[0], s=self.stride[0], d=self.dilation[0])
        pad_w = self.calc_same_pad(i=iw, k=self.kernel_size[1], s=self.stride[1], d=self.dilation[1])

        if pad_h > 0 or pad_w > 0:
            x = F.pad(
                x, [pad_w // 2, pad_w - pad_w // 2, pad_h // 2, pad_h - pad_h // 2]
            )
        return F.conv2d(
            x,
            self.weight,
            self.bias,
            self.stride,
            self.padding,
            self.dilation,
            self.groups,
        )

conv_layer_s2_same = Conv2dSame(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), groups=1, bias=True)
out = conv_layer_s2_same(torch.zeros(1, 3, 224, 224))
```

credit : [Captum](https://github.com/pytorch/captum)

Comment: That's a nice find! For further reference look https://github.com/pytorch/captum/blob/optim-wip/captum/optim/models/_common.py#L144

Answer (score 1):

The formula is: *k = (n - 1) / 2*, where n is kernel size. Here's a visualization:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A complete formula to calculate padding can be found in the documentation of PyTorch:

[image: Conv2D padding Formula Pytorch]

Source: https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html?highlight=conv2d#torch.nn.Conv2d

This formula includes `kernel size`, `stride`, and `dilation`.
Based on this equation, you can iterate using different `padding` sizes (as guesses), until you can find an appropiate value to solve the equation.

Depending on the size of your images, you can create a solver using binary search to find the optimal `padding` value, or you can just try different values incrementing `padding += 1` if the images are not too large.