# Convolution in PyTorch with non-trainable pre-defined kernel

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I would like to introduce a custom layer to my neural network. The mathematical operation should be a discrete 2D cross correlation (or convolution) with a non-trainable kernel. The values in the kernel depend on three things: kernel shape, strides and padding. I intend to multiply the output element-wise with a weight matrix.

PyTorch already has an implementation of a discrete 2D cross correlation class called 'Conv2d', however it generates a random kernel and trains using the entries of said kernel. If possible I would like a class similar to 'Conv2d' that does what I need, to make sure to use my GPU most effectively. I tried implementing this on my own, but couldn't figure out how to obtain the correct shapes for the input array. 'Conv2d' only uses 'in_channels', if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly,you want a `Conv2d` layer with defined kernel and you don't want it to be learnable.

In that case,you can use the `conv2d` function like this:

```py
import torch.nn.functional as F
output_tensor = F.conv2d(input_tensor, your_kernel, ...)
```

the parameter `your_kernel` is your weight matrix,also you need to declare other parameters of the function like `padding` and `stride`

Then you need to set the `requires_grad` attribute to 'False', and exclude it from the optimizer if you don't want it to be learnable.

And about the shape issue ,maybe you wanna [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62166719/padding-same-conversion-to-pytorch-padding/62167204#62167204)